# Using Substring on a Variable in a FOR Statement

Tags: windows, batch-file

What is the correct syntax to test character 1 in each variable in a FOR statement?  My goal is to identify variables from the command line that start with a dash in character 1.

Here is a sample command line:m

```
mysample.bat -p1=1 -p2=2 -p3="abc" myfile
```

Here is what I tried, using substring syntax with `%%~1`:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for %%i in (%*) do if not %%~1:~0,1%=='-' set "filename=%%~i")>nul
```

This gives the following error message:

> "The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid: %~i")>nul"

Comment: You cannot do substitution on a meta variable... but I also doubt anyone will answer this as you ask questions but never mark any as correct or even give many responses.

Comment: I did acknowledge your previous answer to my original question and stated its limitations, so don't be saying I did not react to your answers

Comment: Is there any opportunity to adjust the way the args are presented? or at the very least, their ordering? In my opinion solutions whereby the args to the `.bat` file are presented in a different format or order would improve the robustness of any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let us first look on `mysample.bat` containing just

```
@echo off
for %%I in (%*) do echo %%I
```

and what is output on running in a command prompt window in directory containing `mysample.bat` the command line:

```
mysample.bat -p1=1 -p2=2 -p3="abc" myfile
```

The output is:

```
-p1
1
-p2
2
-p3
"abc"
myfile
```

So the equal sign is interpreted by **FOR** as argument separator like the space character or a comma and some other characters.

So a simple solution to get the **last** argument assigned to an environment variable after code checking if the batch file was called with at least one argument is:

```
set "FileName="
for %%I in (%*) do set "FileName=%%~I"
if defined FileName echo File name is: %FileName%
```

The output is: `File name is: myfile`

But what about calling the batch file with:

```
mysample.bat -p1=1 myfile -p2=2 -p3="abc"
```

Well, it is no surprise that output is wrong with: `File name is: abc`

What about using command **SHIFT**?

```
@echo off
set "ArgNumber=1"
:ArgLoop
if "%~1" == "" goto :EOF
echo Argument %ArgNumber% is: "%~1"
set /A ArgNumber+=1
shift
goto ArgLoop
```

The output on running the batch file with the above list of arguments is:

```
Argument 1 is: "-p1"
Argument 2 is: "1"
Argument 3 is: "myfile"
Argument 4 is: "-p2"
Argument 5 is: "2"
Argument 6 is: "-p3"
Argument 7 is: "abc"
```

So `cmd.exe` interprets also the equal sign as argument separator on `=` not being inside a double quoted argument string. Well, **FOR** is an internal command of `cmd.exe` and so the same code is used to interpret a list of arguments of a batch file as well as in the arguments set of **FOR**.

String substitution is only supported by `cmd.exe` for environment variables. It is not possible to apply them on batch file arguments or on strings assigned to **FOR** loop variables.

So let us look on a batch file code which really evaluates the arguments:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "FileName="
rem Delete all environment variables of which name starts with Parameter.
for /F "delims==" %%I in ('set Parameter 2^>nul') do set "%%I="

:ArgLoop
set "Argument=%~1"
if defined Argument (
    if /I "%Argument:~0,2%" == "-p" (
        set "Parameter %Argument:~2%=%~2"
        shift
    ) else if not defined FileName (
        set "FileName=%~1"
    ) else (
        echo WARNING: Unknown argument: "%~1"
    )
    shift
    goto ArgLoop
)
rem The current argument could be "" which is an empty argument.
rem The current argument could be also just " on being last argument.
rem Don't break the argument loop on such an empty argument, but
rem instead just ignore this empty argument with a warning.
set Argument=%1
if defined Argument (
    echo WARNING: Empty argument: %Argument%
    shift
    goto ArgLoop
)

echo/
if defined FileName echo File name is: "%FileName%"
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('set Parameter 2^>nul') do echo %%I is: "%%~J"
endlocal
```

Let us run this batch file with the command line:

```
mysample.bat "" -p1="First Paramter" myfile -p2 "2nd parameter" What's that -p3,ThirdParameter -p4 Fourth value! "
```

The output is:

```
WARNING: Empty argument: ""
WARNING: Unknown argument: "What's"
WARNING: Unknown argument: "that"
WARNING: Unknown argument: "value!"
WARNING: Empty argument: "

File name is: "myfile"
Parameter 1 is: "First Paramter"
Parameter 2 is: "2nd parameter"
Parameter 3 is: "ThirdParameter"
Parameter 4 is: "Fourth"
```

This output is good in my opinion. It informs the user about obviously wrong specified arguments, but processes nevertheless the valid parameters.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `shift /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `set` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

Answer (score 0):

You cant directly, but can with an auxiliar variable:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (%*) do (
  set aux=%%i
  if not "!aux:~0,1!"=="-" set "filename=!aux!"
)
```

Comment: Need double quotes on IF comparisson to work.